# C# Assign values read from console to dictionary, excluding duplicates

Tags: c#

Please tell me how to add a list of string and int values directly from console.readline input into a dictionary directly without any hard coded or duplicate values.

Example input:

```
sam 78903423
john 232423423
```

Example storage target:

```
Dictionary<string, int> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Comment: Please share your working. Thanks!

Comment: What? Your question is completely unclear. What do you want to achieve? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Have you looked at examples of how to get input from the user?  (For example, your title suggests you're aware of what `Console.ReadLine` is.)  Have you looked at examples of how to use a `Dictionary`?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string line;
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Dictionary<string, int> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, int>();
   string[] parts;
   parts = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, 2);
   phoneBook[parts[0]] = int.Parse(parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation for your answer!

Comment: Thank you so much BluemonkMN.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam i am trying to get user input with list of values(name and phone  number) and directly assign to  dictionary and retrieve them on search.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I don't know what's unclear about this answer, but if you see anything, let me know and I can provide some explanation. The code does exactly what was requested with the specified inputs and outputs so what more is needed?

Comment: minimized,                                                                       
 Dictionary<string, int> phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, int>();                                                                                                
 string[] p_list = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');                                                                      

 phonebook.Add(p_list[0], int.Parse(p_list[1]));